# Linear Probability Model Instead of Logit in Fixed Effects Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, linear-model, stata

In our panel data analysis we estimated a fixed effects linear probability model (LPM) instead of a fixed effects logit regression because our sample size was quite small (600 individuals) and the fixed effects logit decreased our number of observations hugely (to less than 200 at times), while our LPM kept much more observations. Likewise, our logit wouldn't converge as we had to include region indicators and very few people moved such that we had issues of small numbers in cells in logit. Is there a stronger way to explain/justify this, or linear probability models over logits more generally in panel data with fixed effects? We completed our analysis in Stata.

Comment: I'm unclear; are you asking if LPM need to be justified or if your reasons for using an LPM are justified?

Answer (score -1):

If Stata drop observations in a logit model with fixed effects, then this means that you have panels in which the dependent variable is always zero. The fixed effect for that panel then perfectly predicts (i.e. is perfectly collinear with) that outcome. Effectively you are estimating a conditional logit model. This doesn't happen in a linear probability model of course.

Comment: The only way I can see this happening is if the model is saturated and has too many parameters.  General comment: you don't necessarily change models because of a computational problem; try to get to the bottom of the problem first.  And don't change to a worse-fitting model, e.g., a linear model for binary data.

Comment: Irix3537106 is right. This phenomenon is called separation in non linear fixed effect models. Frank Harrell is incorrect - you can get separation even in unsaturated models. This paper is promising for people interested in how to solve it. https://docs.iza.org/dp11182.pdf